# What does this symbol represent in the mobx documentation? an array as another array exported type

Tags: javascript, mobx

In this link: https://mobx-react.js.org/recipes-context line 10 of the create store there is:

```
 friends: [] as TFriend[],
```

What does this mean? Is this Javascript or is this specifically for MobX?

In the beginning theres:

```
export type TFriend = {
  name: string
  isFavorite: boolean
  isSingle: boolean
}
```

Why is there a need to call friends an array as the export type?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking--are you asking what TypeScript is?

Comment: @DaveNewton whats the point of doing `[] as TFriend[]` ?

Comment: So it's typed, otherwise it's just an array.

Answer (score 0):

this line is a typescript line => [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#new-tsx-file-extension-and-as-operator)

'as' is the recommended syntax for **casting** in typescript. so the line of code is equivalent to:

```
friends: <TFriend[]> []
```